# Laravel - How to convert the current url to ControllerName@methodName

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I could get the current url using `{{ URL::current(); }}` in Laravel 4.2. But for some reason I need to get the **current** action, i.e. `ControllerName@methodName`. Please note that I don't want to generate a url to a controller action. How can I get the current action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends, if you are only trying to get the action name, I think you can use Route method.

`Route::currentRouteAction();`

You always have access to current Route by calling

`$currentRoute = Route::current();`

which will probably tell you everything you need to know.

More on Route: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html

Answer (score 1):

You may use `currentRouteAction()` method to get the current route action:

```
$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```